# Can't approve a transaction via uport though i have balance.what is the reason?

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethereumjs, uport

I am using rinkeby network. I am try to save a information to rinkeby network.but a popup apera to sign or approve the transaction via uport. i have balance but i can't sign the transaction.

```
DonationContract.methods
    .setSponsor("raonak92@gmail.com",
    "0xAdED7F5eF369D7cc8cd41DdE5B71637d0CbbE85C",).send(
      transactionObject
      , function(error, transactionHash){
      console.log(error)
      console.log(transactionHash)
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem's solution.It was a bug for uport iphone app. if your iphone is not protected by passcode/pin/fingerprint then this problem occured in my case. I set a passcode for my iphone and then it is working well.